# Why oracle constructs cartesian join with 'start with' statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join, connect-by

I have query like this

```sql
select unique so.object_id, bpi_id
from order_items,
     nc_objects so
where so.object_type_id = 9062352550013045460 /* Sales Order */
start with so.object_id = order_items.object_id
connect by prior so.parent_id = so.object_id
```

Oracle version: `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production`

'explain plan' shows that there is no join conditions between tables so and order_items

[explain plan of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJv3L.png)

Can someone explain me why they are not connected by the `start with` statement?

I rewrited my initial query:

```sql
select unique (select so.object_id
               from nc_objects so
               where so.object_type_id = 9062352550013045460 /* Sales Order */
               start with so.object_id = order_items.object_id
               connect by prior so.parent_id = so.object_id) so_id,
              bpi_id
from order_items
```

It works, but only because of `so` have one row per `order_items` row.

Comment: `start with` is generally used to provide the starting point for your hiearchy query. Your first query is joining two tables without any condition. Hence, It is considered as a `CROSS JOIN`. You have given join condition in `START WITH` clause which is not how join works in Oracle. In second query, You are giving the `order_items.object_id` per row(Specific value) to start the hierarchy query. so it is working fine.

Comment: You shouldn't use comma joins in the first place. I admit that Oracle was very late in adopting explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN ... ON/USING`, etc. defined in the SQL standard of 1992). But still, that was in 2001; more than twenty years ago! Use explicit joins. Don't use that out-dated comma join syntax. With explicit joins you would have noticed that you are applying a cartesian join.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```sql
select so.object_id,
       bpi_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(order_items.object_id||':'||so.object_id || ':' || bpi_id, ',') AS path
from   order_items,
       nc_objects so
where  so.object_type_id = 100/* Sales Order */
start with so.object_id = order_items.object_id
connect by prior so.parent_id = so.object_id
```

Then for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE order_items (object_id, bpi_id) AS
SELECT LEVEL, CHR(64+LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE nc_objects (object_id, object_type_id, parent_id) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 100, LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL+10, 200, LEVEL + 10 - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

The output is:

| OBJECT_ID | BPI_ID | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ,1:1:A |
| 2 | B | ,2:2:B |
| 1 | A | ,2:2:B,1:1:A |
| 1 | C | ,2:2:B,3:1:C |
| 1 | B | ,2:2:B,2:1:B |
| 3 | C | ,3:3:C |
| 2 | A | ,3:3:C,1:2:A |
| 1 | A | ,3:3:C,1:2:A,1:1:A |
| 1 | C | ,3:3:C,1:2:A,3:1:C |
| 1 | B | ,3:3:C,1:2:A,2:1:B |
| 2 | C | ,3:3:C,3:2:C |
| 1 | A | ,3:3:C,3:2:C,1:1:A |
| 1 | C | ,3:3:C,3:2:C,3:1:C |
| 1 | B | ,3:3:C,3:2:C,2:1:B |
| 2 | B | ,3:3:C,2:2:B |
| 1 | A | ,3:3:C,2:2:B,1:1:A |
| 1 | C | ,3:3:C,2:2:B,3:1:C |
| 1 | B | ,3:3:C,2:2:B,2:1:B |

You can see from the path that the `so.object_id` only equals the `order_items.object_id` for the `START WITH` row but for all the descendant rows every `so.object_id` is connected to every `order_items.object_id` with a `CROSS JOIN`.

If you want to rewrite it as a recursive query then:

```sql
WITH data (oi_id, so_id, bpi_id, parent_id, object_type_id) AS (
  SELECT oi.object_id,
         so.object_id,
         oi.bpi_id,
         so.parent_id,
         so.object_type_id
  FROM   order_items oi
         CROSS JOIN nc_objects so
),
hierarchy (so_id, bpi_id, parent_id, object_type_id, path) AS (
  SELECT so_id,
         bpi_id,
         parent_id,
         object_type_id,
         ','||oi_id||':'||so_id||':'||bpi_id
  FROM   data
  WHERE  so_id = oi_id
UNION ALL
  SELECT d.so_id,
         d.bpi_id,
         d.parent_id,
         d.object_type_id,
         h.path || ','||d.oi_id||':'||d.so_id||':'||d.bpi_id
  FROM   data d
         INNER JOIN hierarchy h
         ON (h.parent_id = d.so_id)
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY so_id SET order_id
select so_id AS object_id,
       bpi_id,
       path
from   hierarchy
where  object_type_id = 100
```

Which outputs the same.

You can see that the join condition `WHERE  so_id = oi_id` is only applied on the first join of the recursive query, the equivalent of the `START WITH` clause of the hierarchical query, and is not applied to any of the rows generated in the recursive part of the query, the equivalent of the `CONNECT BY` clause; therefore, it is not appropriate to join the two tables using the `START BY` clause as that only applies to the first row of the hierarchy and the rest are `CROSS JOIN`ed.

---

If you did want to `JOIN` at each level of the hierarchy then don't use a `CROSS JOIN` and use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```sql
select so.object_id,
       bpi_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(order_items.object_id||':'||so.object_id || ':' || bpi_id, ',') AS path
from   order_items
       INNER JOIN nc_objects so
       ON so.object_id = order_items.object_id
where  so.object_type_id = 100 /* Sales Order */
connect by prior so.parent_id = so.object_id
```

Which outputs:

| OBJECT_ID | BPI_ID | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ,1:1:A |
| 2 | B | ,2:2:B |
| 1 | A | ,2:2:B,1:1:A |
| 3 | C | ,3:3:C |
| 2 | B | ,3:3:C,2:2:B |
| 1 | A | ,3:3:C,2:2:B,1:1:A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0MKopYo)